# How can I make a shell script indicate that it was successful?

Tags: sh

If I have a basic .sh file containing the following script code:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf "MyFolder"
```

How do I make this running script file display results to the terminal that will indicate if the directory removal was successful?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to make it say it was successful. You could have it say something only on error ✖, and then silence means success ✔.

That's how the Unix philosophy works:

> The *rule of silence*, also referred to as the *silence is golden* rule, is an important part of the *Unix philosophy* that states that when a program has nothing surprising, interesting or useful to say, it should say nothing. It means that well-behaved programs should treat their users' attention and concentration as being valuable and thus perform their tasks as unobtrusively as possible. That is, silence in itself is a virtue. http://www.linfo.org/rule_of_silence.html

That's the way `rm` itself behaves.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the general case, as suggested by your question's title, you can run your script with `sh -x scriptname` to see what it's doing. It's also quite common to write diagnostic output into the script itself, and control it with an option.

```
#!/bin/sh
verbose=false
case $1 in -v | --verbose )
    verbose=true
    shift ;;
esac

say () {
    $verbose || return
    echo "$0: $@" >&2
}

say "Removing $dir ..."
rm -rf "$dir" || say "Failed."
```

If you run this script without any options, it will run silently, like a well-behaved Unix utility should. If you run it with the `-v` option, it will print some diagnostics to standard error.

Answer (score -1):

```
rm -rf "My Folder" && echo "Done" || echo "Error!"
```

You can read more on creating a sequence of pipelines [in bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists)

Comment: `rm -rf ` always return true

Comment: @sputnick Unless it fails.  (eg, if the user does not have permission to remove the directory.)

Comment: Although it is technically correct to say this is a sequence of pipelines, it is just a sequence of simple commands.  (A simple command is a trivial pipeline containing no pipes.)

Answer (score -2):

In the bash (and other similar shells) the `?` environment variable gives you the exit code of the last executed command. So you can do:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf "My Folder"
echo $?
```

**UPDATE**

If once the `rm` command has been executed the directory doesn't exist (because it has been successfully removed or because it didn't exist when the command was executed) the script will print 0. If the directory exists (which will mean that the command has been unable to remove it) then the script will print an exit code other than 0. If I understand properly the question this is exactly the requested behavior. If it is not, please correct me.

Comment: Epic fail, rm don't exit > 0 when the dir isn't there

Comment: @e-zero I've updated my answer. I hope it is clearer now and helpful to you.

Comment: This means your script no longer itself exits with a failure when `rm` does. That's a step backwards from the original behavior, when `if cleanup-script; then echo "cleanup script succeeded" >&2; else echo "cleanup script failed" >&2; fi` would work, if the script in question were saved under the `cleanup-script` name.

Comment: `rm -rf "My Folder"; rm_retval=$?` would let you *both* `echo "rm exited with status: $rm_retval" >&2` and then `exit "$rm_retval"`. If you use `$?` without saving it, you can do only one or the other, since `echo` itself is a command that changes `$?` when it runs.

Answer (score -3):

The previous answers was wrong : `rm` don't exit with error code > 0 when the dir isn't present.

Instead, I recommend to use :

```
dir='/path/to/dir'
if [[ -d $dir ]]; then
    rm -rf "$dir"
fi
```

If you want `rm` to return a status, remove `-f` flag.

Example on Linux Mint (the dir doesn't exists):

```
$ rm -rf /tmp/sdfghjklm
$ echo $?
0

$ rm -r /tmp/sdfghjklm
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: The answers were right. You should have a look to the meaning of the -f option in the man page.

Comment: The -f option ignore non existent files and never prompts. If you execute it directly with a non existing directory on your terminal you will get no error. So $? must return a 0.

Comment: The fact that the output of the command rm -rf is somehow unexpected to you doesn't mean that the $? doesn't work. It works perfectly so please edit the part of your answer saying that my answer is wrong.